# Jaybird with JPA on UUID field (char(16) character set octets)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, firebird, jaybird

I have problem with UUID ID fields defined by domain

```
CREATE DOMAIN OCTET16 AS CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS;
```

I have defined AttributeConverter for jpa as
    import java.util.UUID;

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

import com.ekser.nakkash.icdv.tools.UUIDTools;

@Converter
public class UUIDAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, byte[]> {
    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID arg0) {
        return UUIDTools.asBytes((UUID) arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] arg0) {
        return UUIDTools.asUUID((byte[])arg0);
    }
}
```

and defined jpa fields as

```
@Id
@Convert(converter = UUIDAttributeConverter.class)
private UUID id;
```

but jpa (Eclipselink+Eclipse Gemini) gives error as it tries to convert not binary presentation but textual form of 36 character

I suppose problem is that jaybird gives type of field as CHAR(16), (I have checked with ResultSetMetaData), I know that there is option `octetsAsBytes`, I have used it with jbdc url like

```
jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost:D:/aktarma-12-13/VERI.FDB?octetsAsBytes=true
```

with no result.

My setup is pretty complicated

```
Java 1.8
Efxclipse 2.4.0 RCP
Firebird 2.5.6
Jaybird 2.2.12 JDK_1.8
HikariCP 2.4.1
EclipseLink 2.6.4
Eclipse Gemini 1.2.0.M1
```

So I think when ResultSetMetaData will give me type of field as BINARY the problem will gone. But how? Any suggestions.

I just not want to hold ids as char(32) or char(36).

**Edit:** After switching to Jaybird 3.beta-2, 
one can clearly see on third line `invalid stream header: F1505533`. This is a part ASCII decoded id (char(16) character set octets). How to make JPA to accept this value as raw byte and make it pass to UUIDAttributeConverter class??!!

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-66] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Could not deserialize object from byte array.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: F1505533
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[id-->YAZDIRMA_TURLERI.ID]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.ekser.nakkash.icdv.pojo.YazdirmaTuru --> [DatabaseTable(YAZDIRMA_TURLERI)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:484)
    at com.ekser.nakkash.icdv.gui.MainPartIcdv.lambda$1(MainPartIcdv.java:180)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-66] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Could not deserialize object from byte array.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: F1505533
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[id-->YAZDIRMA_TURLERI.ID]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.ekser.nakkash.icdv.pojo.YazdirmaTuru --> [DatabaseTable(YAZDIRMA_TURLERI)])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException.notDeserializable(DescriptorException.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.SerializedObjectConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(SerializedObjectConverter.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.getObjectValue(AbstractDirectMapping.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.foundation.AbstractDirectMapping.valueFromRow(AbstractDirectMapping.java:1220)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1539)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1175)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: F1505533
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.serializers.JavaSerializer.deserialize(JavaSerializer.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.SerializedObjectConverter.convertDataValueToObjectValue(SerializedObjectConverter.java:142)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: F1505533
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(CustomObjectInputStream.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.serializers.JavaSerializer.deserialize(JavaSerializer.java:53)
    ... 80 more
```

Comment: Is the driver able to handle the byte[] when writing - is the problem only when reading?  If so, just have your converter handle the character string returned from the driver.

Comment: Could you try with [Jaybird 3-beta-2](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/releases/tag/v3.0.0-beta-2), it will handle `char(16) character set octets` as type `binary` always, see [Character set OCTETS handled as JDBC (VAR)BINARY](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/3.0.0-beta-2/release_notes.html#character-set-octets-handled-as-jdbc-varbinary). The `octetsAsBytes` in Jaybird 2.2 is unfortunately not applied consistently (although it should apply in the case of `ResultSetMetaData`, it doesn't work if for example `getObject` is used on the result set).

Comment: BTW: It might be helpful to include the actual error in your question.

Comment: I have tried with Jaybird 3-beta-2, same deal. I try to post error log.

Comment: The invalid stream header seems to suggest it is trying to use Java serialization instead of converting using the `AttributeConverter`

Comment: Did you list the converter in your persistence context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a simple project using eclipselink 2.6.4 to test this, and both with Jaybird 2.2.12 (setting `octetsAsBytes=true` is required) and Jaybird 3.0.0-beta-2 it works:

Code also on: https://gist.github.com/mrotteveel/273aa9e836880211820f54ff21164ec1

Todo Entity:

```
package com.example.eclipselink.entity;

import com.example.eclipselink.converter.UUIDAttributeConverter;

import javax.persistence.Convert;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class Todo {

    @Id
    @Convert(converter = UUIDAttributeConverter.class)
    private UUID id;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

UUIDAttributeConverter:

```
package com.example.eclipselink.converter;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.UUID;

@Converter
public class UUIDAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, byte[]> {

    @Override
    public byte[] convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID uuid) {
        if (uuid == null) return null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16];
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
        bb.putLong(uuid.getMostSignificantBits());
        bb.putLong(uuid.getLeastSignificantBits());
        return buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(byte[] bytes) {
        if (bytes == null) return null;
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        long high = bb.getLong();
        long low = bb.getLong();
        return new UUID(high, low);
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package com.example.eclipselink;

import com.example.eclipselink.entity.Todo;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Main {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        // read the existing entries and write to console
        Query q = em.createQuery("select t from Todo t");
        List<Todo> todoList = q.getResultList();
        for (Todo todo : todoList) {
            System.out.println(todo.getId());
        }
        System.out.println("Size: " + todoList.size());

        // create new todo
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
        em.persist(todo);
        em.getTransaction().commit();

        em.close();
    }
}
```

Persistence context:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.example.eclipselink.entity.Todo</class>
        <class>com.example.eclipselink.converter.UUIDAttributeConverter</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/d:/data/db/fb3/eclipselink.fdb?charSet=UTF-8&amp;octetsAsBytes=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sysdba" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="masterkey" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

DDL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TODO
(
  ID char(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_TODO PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Output after a few runs:

```
[EL Info]: 2017-01-13 15:59:14.733--ServerSession(1139700454)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: connection: 2017-01-13 15:59:15.093--ServerSession(1139700454)--/file:/D:/Development/project/eclipselink/target/classes/_todos login successful
4c062d69-849e-4946-8e25-edfc5d7441be
dac10396-cfe2-4fb0-b048-65f954a82da5
8dab770e-ebd2-4ebc-a29b-4b8aae0b449a
9d376c67-fdc5-4e21-8013-f71cde5119aa
Size: 4
```

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, I also tested it using a domain like you mention in your question.

Comment: Mark, you are my hero! You are saving me for second time. I will not forget this. My code was ok. I was just I forget to annotate uuid field with @Converter annotation. In my other AttibuteConverters there are (autoApply = true). ....